# Google Material Design ALL 24 Elevations

Tags: css, material-design, shadow

I've been really interested in the concept of material design lately, but there is one thing that I have not been able to overcome. The way to create the elevations that Google stated. I've already been looking for a month, but have only found the solution to the old material guidelines. What I'm looking for is the new 24 elevations, not the original 5 elevations. If anybody has a solution, I would be happy to hear.

*Google's own "material" websites doesn't seem to be using the new guidelines either.

Google's Guidlines Link:
https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html

I thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[material-shadows](https://github.com/mrmlnc/material-shadows) is a library that uses these new units. However it doesn't currently interpolate values. The only supported levels are: 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 16, 24.

I [added an issue](https://github.com/mrmlnc/material-shadows/issues/7) that suggests interpolation.